C extension for postgres using arrays
Hello i am trying to create an extension which would take an array as input and add 5 to it and then return the output it need not change the original array
    #include "postgres.h"
    #include "fmgr.h"
    #include "utils/array.h"
    #include "catalog/pg_type.h"

    #ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
    #endif

    PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(arr);

    Datum 
    arr(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
    {
        Datum arry = PG_GETARG_DATUM(0);
        ArrayType *inputArray = DatumGetArrayTypeP(arry);
        PG_RETURN_DATUM(arry);
    }


i wrote a script to take an input array and return it as is.
ArrayType *inputArray = DatumGetArrayTypeP(arry); ----> when i try to type cast it to ArrayType the db looses it connection.
I have also tried the following code
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "utils/array.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(my_return_array_as_is);

Datum
my_return_array_as_is(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    // Get the input array
    ArrayType *inputArray = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0);

    // Normally, you might process the array here

    // Return the array as is
    PG_RETURN_ARRAYTYPE_P(inputArray);
}

but this one doesnt work at all
ArrayType *inputArray = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0) ----> it gives an error right over here
SQL FILE
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retarr1(int[])
RETURNS int[]
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'retarr1'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;

sql query - SELECT retarr1(ARRAY[10,20])
I am not sure what the issue is i am using windows 11 and gcc as my compiler below are the compilation commands i use to create a dll for POSTGRES 16.2
gcc  -I "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/include/server/port/win32/" -I "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/include/server" -I "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/include"  -o arr.o -c arr.c

gcc -g -shared -o arr.dll arr.o -L"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib" -lpostgres

Thanks.

Perhaps you could be more specific than "does not work at all".

Well I am able to compile the dll and add the extension to the db but when I run the select query the db seems to loose it's connection.

Sounds like a crash. Collect a stack trace and add it to the question.
